# TCL regsub multiple special characters in one shot

Tags: tcl, regsub

Is there a way to add escape '\' into a string with multiple special characters?

Example input : `a/b[1]/c/d{3}`
Desired outcome : `a\/b\[1\]\/c\/d\{3\}`

I've done it in multiple regsubs one special character at a time. But is there a way to do it in one shot?

Comment: Dang it the forum editor swallowed my backslashes.
My desired output is supposed to be a<backslash>/b<backslash>[1<backslash>]<backslash>/c<backslash>/d<backslash>{3<backslash>}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply escape all non-word characters:

```
set input {a/b[1]/c/d{3}}
set output [regsub -all {\W} $input {\\&}]
puts $output
```

```
a\/b\[1\]\/c\/d\{3\}
```

ref: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm and https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to use is to build a RE character set (`[…]`) and use that. You have to be a bit careful with those in some cases (some characters are special in them, especially `^`, `]`, `-` and `\`), but it's not too difficult.

```
regsub -all {[][/{}]} $input {\\&}
```

However, if you can use character classes (such as `\W` or `[^\w]`) then it's a lot simpler and easier to read. Most common cases of needing to apply backslashes work with those.